# how do you scale a pdf file with lp?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I am having problems with printing using lp.   I have a PDF file and when I open it using evince and print it from there it prints fine.   But since I want to print from within a script I want to use lp.   When I print the same file with lp parts at the border are missing; I am assuming that is the printer margin that lp is cuttting off.   I then tried

> lp -o scaling=50 myfile.pdf

and it does not make a difference.

lpoptions output is

> auth-info-required=none copies=1 device-uri=usb://Canon/iP4500%20series finishings=3 job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=0 media=iso_a4_210x297mm number-up=1 orientation-requested=3 printer-commands=none printer-info='Canon iP4500 series' printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=true printer-location=lpt1 printer-make-and-model='Canon PIXMA iP4500 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.5 Simplified' printer-state=5 printer-state-change-time=1441008473 printer-state-reasons=paused printer-type=176156 printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon-iP4500-series sides=one-sided

I had to install a Canon printer driver for Linux and my suspicion now is that lp is scaling it down and the printer driver is scaling it up again.

Can anybody point me in the direction how the printing in lp and evince works?    Are they not both using cups?    And why is the scaling option not working in lp (as a matter of fact none of the page margin options works either)?

Any hint would be appreciated.